# How to check if a host is reachable?

Tags: java, sockets

```
boolean reachable = false;

while (true){
    Socket socket = null;
    while (reachable == false && (System.currentTimeMillis() < (CUR_TIME + 1000))){
        try {
            socket = new Socket(hostname, 80);
            reachable = true;
        } catch ( UnknownHostException e) {
            reachable = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to eventually call `status = httpConnection.getResponseCode();`, but if the user inputs an unreachable host, there is an error. Therefore, I'm using the above code to make sure the host is available. However, `reachable` always returns as false, even if the host is in good standing (as shown by other methods).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HttpURLConnection**:

```
try{
    URL url = new URL("http://tes23123t.com");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();
    int respCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(respCode);
}catch(UnknownHostException e){
    System.out.println("Unknown Host!!");
}
```

Or you could use OKHttp library if you prefer easier implementation